# Google Cloud API: Can't create domain mapping with App Engine service account

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to use the `googleapiclient` Python SDK to create a domain mapping for my App Engine app. I'm using the "App Engine default service account" to authenticate, which works (I can get the list of domain mappings). However, when I try to create a mapping, I get the following error:

> Caller is not authorized to administer the domain 'abc.*[mydomain]*'. If you own 'abc.*[mydomain]*', you can obtain authorization by verifying ownership of the domain, or any of its parent domains, via the Webmaster Central portal: [https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/verification?domain=abc.*[mydomain]*](https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/verification?domain=abc._[mydomain]_). We recommend verifying ownership of the largest scope you wish to use with subdomains (eg. verify 'example.com' if you wish to map 'subdomain.example.com').

The same call works in the [API Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.domainMappings/create) without any issues.

I tried giving the service account the Owner role in the IAM console, to no avail.

(I haven't tried running it from within App Engine; presumably that works, but I'd really like to be able to test this part of my app locally.)

Comment: 1) Go to Google Webmaster Central. Select your domain. Under `verified owners` click `Add an owner. 2) Another method: Go to Google Search Console. Select your domain. Under `Settings -> Users and permissions` you can control who has access. You can add a service account as an `Owner`.

Comment: @JohnHanley Do you want to make this into an answer and I'll accept it, or should I write it up?

Comment: Take my comments and then create an answer with more details based upon your situation. This will help others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to John Hanley for pointing me in the right direction.

1. Go to the [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console) and sign in
2. Navigate to "Settings" (towards the bottom of the menu)
3. Select "Users and Permissions"
4. Click the "more" (three vertical dots) button next to your email address, then "Manage property owners"
5. Choose your domain from the list
6. Click "Add an owner" at the bottom of the page

Comment: thanks man, it helped me a lot!