# Google Cloud Run domain mappings from Cloud Build - service account problem with verified domain

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to set up a Google Cloud Build pipeline, which will deploy an image to Cloud Run and create a domain mapping. Everything works fine in Web UI, but when I do `gcloud bet run domain-mappings create ...` in Cloud Build step I'm getting error message:

`ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.domain-mappings.create) The provided domain does not appear to be verified for the current account so a domain mapping cannot be created. Visit [https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains/] for more information.`

The domain for which I'm setting the mapping is hosted also in Google Cloud (Cloud Domains) and dns are managed via Cloud DNS. As I said, using Web UI works like a charm.

I tried to verify the domain using generated ID and putting it to TXT dns record - without luck. I don't see any option to "authorize" Service Account which is running on behalf of Cloud Build, nor see any legit IAM permission.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 4):

OK, I've found the solution here: [Google Cloud API: Can't create domain mapping with App Engine service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62144372/google-cloud-api-cant-create-domain-mapping-with-app-engine-service-account)

Added cloudbuild service account to the Google Search Console for given domain as an owner and it works!